# Installing a certificate to the LocalMachine/Root store is not supported

Tags: azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have a couple of certificates that I need to add to the worker role which have to get installed in the Cloud service's Root Certification store upon deployment.

I added the following lines in the service definition of my worker role

Upon building the Worker Role project, I get the following error

Installing a certificate to the LocalMachine/Root store is not supported

Any thoughts on why this could be happening  ?

Certificate name="Internal Root" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" 
Certificate name="SSL Corp CA" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" />

Comment: Certificate name="Internal Root" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" 
      <Certificate name="SSL Corp CA" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root"

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft by default does not allow direct import to the trusted root store. Even if you give the Storename as "CA" , the cert will be downloaded only to the intermediate cert store. You will have to write a startup task with elevated permissions to move the cert to root store. However, you need to do this only if your SSl cert is issued by a provider who is not included in the Microsoft root certificate program . If a provider is part of the root certificate program, the root certificate corresponding to your SSL certificate will automatically be downloaded to your Azure instance when you deploy it.

refer:  http://thetechnologychronicle.blogspot.in/2013/11/ssl-cert-considerations-in-windows-azure.html

The Workaround is discussed in the following thread from MSDN
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5db1118-0185-4dc7-a6d7-d62ce4cc9e27/azure-cloud-service-install-certificate-in-trusted-root?forum=windowsazuredevelopment

and also a Code example for OnStart().

https://rupertmaier.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/deploying-a-certificate-into-the-trusted-root-store-in-windows-azure-cloud-services/

-Nithin